# C - Why this function prints the array as NULL Strings?

Tags: c

I'm having a problem dealing with an array in C. You see, this is a portion of my code which basically reads a file and organizes coordinates of the vertices of parcels of the 3rd-levels administrive divisions in Portugal - which we call Freguesias. In this part of the exercise, I need to write the name of all 2rd-levels administrive divisions - Concelhos (which is already well defined in my code in the array Cartography cartography, that isn't the problem) that appear in the file.

I want to do a function that shows what Concelhos appear in the file and I want to write with this exact subfunctions and functions so I can change some things later, but for some reason it doesn't printf the strings in "command_list_concelhos", it just prints NULL strings. I don't know why this happens, specially since it does rightly so if I do a printf inside and outside the for in "read_string_concelhos".

Sorry if this question is wrongly explained, too big or just a small detail that I am missing, but I don't have a better way to explain it...

```
#define MAX_STRING 256
#define MAX_NAMES  50

typedef char String[MAX_STRING];

typedef struct {
    String list[MAX_NAMES];
    int n_strings;
}   StringList;

int read_string_concelhos(StringList s ,Cartography cartography, int n)
{
    int i, j=1;
    strcpy (s.list[j-1], cartography[0].identification.concelho);
    for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        if ( strcmp(cartography[i].identification.concelho, s.list[j-1]) != 0){
            strcpy(s.list[j] , cartography[i].identification.concelho);
            j++;
        }
    }
    return j; // n_strings
}

void command_list_concelhos(Cartography cartography, int n)
{
    StringList s;
    s.n_strings = read_string_concelhos(s, cartography, n);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < s.n_strings; i++ )
    {
        printf("\n", s.list[i]);
    }
}
```

[Fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzYey.png)

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zYLm.png)

Comment: When the code passes `s` to `read_string_concelhos`, `s` is a ***copy*** of the structure. So any changes made to `s` only affect the copy. The `s` in `command_list_concelhos` is not changed when `read_string_concelhos` changes its copy of `s`.

Comment: @user3386109 Would you like to turn that into an answer?

Comment: @user3386109 I do understand what's the problem, but can you tell me how can I fix this please? I suppose I'm missing some detail.

Answer (score 1):

`int read_string_concelhos(StringList s ,Cartography cartography, int n)` 
should be changed to
`int read_string_concelhos(StringList* s ,Cartography cartography, int n)`

And inside the function `int read_string_concelhos(StringList* s ,Cartography cartography, int n) { ... }`, all `s.list[...]` should be changed to `s->list[...]`. In this way, parameter `s` is a pointer therefore `strcmp` would paste to `s` declared in `command_list_concelhos` which is the desired behaviour.